# django model object attribute track updates / edits / changes by date

Tags: django, logging

I have a django model class e.g.

```
class BankAccount (model.Models):
    value = models.PositiveSmallIntegerField(default=0)
```

I would like to edit this value and edit it on a weekly basis e.g.

wk1: value = 1
wk2: value = 30
...
wk 50: value = 70

QUESTION:

I would like to keep track of the value changes and be able to display the value for the previous weeks:

e.g. today is wk 40 and value = 60 and I would like to check what was the value in wk 30, wk 20, wk 10 etc ...

How to do this in django?

My only idea I have at the moment is to either create a new object for every other week and keep all the objects OR track the changes in the model with off-the-shelf app?

Does anybody have any better idea?

Comment: https://github.com/treyhunner/django-simple-history

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To me it would make sense to have a `transaction` model with dates and times where you store each value then update the `BankAccount` value as appropriate.

You would apply transactions to the transactions table and update the balance/value of `BankAccount`.

This would be the standard way to design something like this. It also gives you a safety-net, history should something go wrong allowing a recalculation of of the value etc.

The other option is to just have a `transactions` model but with an additional field `current_balance`. This would be used to store the balance effective right after that transaction executed. Thus, the latest transaction record for a user and currency also contains their current balance.