# django object updates, track and compare changes

Tags: django, updates

I have an object which has an attribute value. Value can be updated on a weekly basis e.g. Monday by user.

I want to be able to display object value by week number e.g wk35 value, wk36 value ... wk40 value.

I want to be able to compare historical values and get percentage change.

What I do not know is:

Should I create attributes for my object e.g.

datecreated
dateupdated (so it contains final last update on specific day)
dateedited (so user can edit value multiple times during a day)

I understand user can edit value few time but should be able to update final edit once on that day.

I am struggling with a concept of above idea. I have started to read about simple-history which can help me achieve tracking changes but I do not not how to achieve what's written above.

My model class is:

```
class ZoneSubStage(models.Model):
    zone = models.ForeignKey(Zone)
    substage = models.ForeignKey(SubStage)
    value = models.PositiveSmallIntegerField(default=0)
    slug = models.SlugField(unique=True)
    history = HistoricalRecords()
    created = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
    date = models.DateField(null=True)
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [django model object attribute track updates / edits / changes by date](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32616559/django-model-object-attribute-track-updates-edits-changes-by-date)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There might be some third party modules that do this for you but my best home brew suggestion is a logging table. If you need the log entry to be unique by date you would just need to modify the `ZoneSubStage.save()` method to lookup a `ZoneSubStageLog` by current date before simply creating a new one (which I think you need but will leave to you).

```
from django.db import transaction

class ZoneSubStage(models.Model):
    zone = models.ForeignKey(Zone)
    substage = models.ForeignKey(SubStage)
    value = models.PositiveSmallIntegerField(default=0)
    slug = models.SlugField(unique=True)
    history = HistoricalRecords()
    created = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
    date = models.DateField(null=True)

    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super(ZoneSubStage, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        self.value_original = self.value

    def save(self, **kwargs):
        with transaction.atomic():
            response = super(ZoneSubStage, self).save(**kwargs)
            if self.value_original != self.value:
                zone_log = ZoneSubStageLog()
                zone_log.zone_sub_stage = self
                zone_log.value = self.original_value
                zone_log.save()
            return response

class ZoneSubStageLog(models.Model):
    zone_sub_stage = models.ForeignKey(ZoneSubStage)
    value = models.PositiveSmallIntegerField(default=0)
    date = models.DateField(auto_now_add=True)
```

Answer (score 0):

This is a very broad/high-level question, but basically you should store historical data/changes separate from your model.

Think of it this way: your model is a living entity, and it has a *current state*. At regular intervals, you can take *snapshots* of that state (the data). Later, you can use those snapshots you made to piece together the model's history (visualize how it has changed over time, for instance). This is basically the **[Memento pattern](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Memento_pattern)**.

So, consider your needs. What "resolution" should your model snapshot have? That is, should it store every data point or just a few? Should it store every single change by every single user, or just take a snapshot once a week? If it's just once a week, as you suggested, just run a cron job that copies the model data to another model... or another database, or you could even write it down to a flat JSON or CSV file!

Or... if you want to be able to reconstruct the model exactly as it was at a certain point in time, consider a package like **[django-reversion](https://github.com/etianen/django-reversion)**.

On the other hand, if there are just one one or two Really Important Numbers to track over time, you could just create a model that stores the id of the originating model as a foreign key, the important number values, and a timestamp.

EDIT: Dotcomly's answer provides a good implementation if all you want to keep is the one ZoneSubStage.value. To better decouple the log from the model, I'd suggest using a **[`post_save` signal](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/ref/signals/#post-save)** to create the log entry, instead of overriding the models' save method.

Comment: I try to create Django app which can replace excel files. At the moment user provides me with an excel file predefined for every new project and submits an update weekly.  Cell marked in Grey are predefined and always constant for each project. Cell defined in Green are defined by user once in the beginning of the project. Pink cells must be updated weekly and file submited to me weekly. I try to create app which will store it all data and all weekly updates so I can track changes on a weekly basis.

Comment: Here is example file: https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/6543156/ProjectDjango.xls

Comment: I have created my models and get funcionality so I can create new project with new stages and substages and add new zones and edit zonesubstage values. Although I struggle now with weekly updates.